# Changing icon of another menuitem in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a menu in ActionBar. "gecerlidil" is menu item and "ingilizce" and "turkce" are sub-menu of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/gecerlidil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ing"
        android:title="ingilizce"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/ingilizce"
            android:title="EN"
            android:icon="@drawable/ing"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/turkce"
            android:title="TR"
            android:icon="@drawable/tur"/>
    </menu>
        </item>
</menu>
```

When i click `ingilizce` menu item or `turkce` menu item `gecerlidil` menu icon  will change but i couldn't succeed it. I think i will do it in `onOptionsItemSelected` function.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you really asking a question or telling us what you achieved?

Comment: i am telling you what i can't achieve

Comment: `private Menu menu;`
In your onCreateOptionsMenu()
`this.menu = menu;`
then in the OptionsItemSelected

`menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));` just get the item position that you need

Comment: Thank you very much iBobb it works except one thing, getDrawable is deprecated for Api 22.
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher,null)); works perfectly

Comment: forgot to mention that sorry, if you are willing to accept it as answer, i posted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a global variable `private Menu menu;`

In your onCreateOptionsMenu()

`this.menu = menu;`

then in the OptionsItemSelected 
`menu.getItem(0).setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ic‌​_launcher,null));`

Answer (score 0):

action bar is deprecated actually in android, so i cant help you...

but i recommended you use toolbar, is like action bar but you can do this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="156dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and you will change this ImageView or ImageButton using a menu xml and onOptionsItemSelected()

i hope that this will help you